# VBA: Openning, Editing, Saving... works when the VB editor is open, not when closed?

Tags: excel, save, vba

I am trying to open multiple excel files (97,2003,2007,2010.. etc.), edit them and save them. My macro works if I have the Visual Basic Editor open (Alt+F11) and asked to enable Macros in the beginning, but if my VB editor is closed, it opens the file and stops on saving the first file.

I using this command:

```
Set OpenWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
```

where `OpenWB` is declared as a `Workbook` object. That works fine, even open Macro files without being asked? However when I open the Visual-Basic Editor (Alt-F11) and I have that

Then I edit data. Then save using this command:

```
' Save File
OpenWB.Save
```

The code try to save but then breaks right there. I have tried to enable & disable the `Application.DisplayAlerts` (True/False).

The problem is that, I can't run it with the VB Editor open, because I need the macro warning to be disabled as I have 1000+ files. Yet without it open the code doens't pass the save code line.

Example of a portion of the code:

```
'Path
FilePath = FL.Cells(FileListCount, 1).Value

' Begin first loop
While FilePath <> ""

    ' Alerts?
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Open File
    Set OpenWB = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

    ' Alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' Enter Replacement Loop
    ReplacementCount = 1
    ID = Ctrl.Cells(ReplacementCount + 11, 2).Value

    While ID <> ""
        OpenWB.Sheets(Ctrl.Cells(ReplacementCount + 11, 4).Value).Range(Ctrl.Cells(ReplacementCount + 11, 5).Value).Value = Ctrl.Cells(ReplacementCount + 11, 3).Value
        ReplacementCount = ReplacementCount + 1
        ID = Ctrl.Cells(ReplacementCount + 11, 2).Value
    Wend

    ' Save File
    OpenWB.Save

    ' Close file
    OpenWB.Close 

    ' status
    FL.Cells(FileListCount, 2).Value = "***** UPDATED *****"

    ' Increment counter
    FileListCount = FileListCount + 1

    ' Call new path
    FilePath = FL.Cells(FileListCount, 1).Value
Wend
```

Comment: Do you see an error message?  If yes, what is it?

Comment: Thats the thing - VBeditor Open: Security Notice Question?,  - VBeditor Close: Stop after saving the first file no error.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested.

Have your already tried:

```
Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
Set OpenWB = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'ur goes here code

OpenWB.Activate

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

It would eliminate both save and close lines.